# Token contract and crowdsale contract deploy

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, tokens, remix, crowdsale

I am Testing with an Ethereum Based token contract and i would need some help  deploying the Token contract and Crowdsale contract.

I already have done this, deploying booth contracts and allocating tokens to the crowdsale contract from the token contract but when i send ether to the crowdsale contract i do not get sent back the tokens.

These are the [Token contract](https://github.com/WildCryptoICO/Wild-Crypto-Token/blob/master/WILDToken.sol) and [Crowdsale contract](https://github.com/WildCryptoICO/Wild-Crypto-Token/blob/master/Crowdsale.sol).

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting a post well.

Comment: I've had the same issue. Did you find a solution?